# XML RPC Call in android

Tags: android

Guys, I want to get xml from RPC calling. But I don't know how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The [**android-xmlrpc**](https://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/) project might help -- I've used it a couple of times, in simple situations, and it did get the job done.